# Does Firefox 57+ use extensions.* prefs for individual extensions anymore?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile, webex

Previous to Firefox 57, extensions stored prefs in `extensions.*` within `prefs.js`.

With WebExtensions, do extensions ever store their prefs within `prefs.js`?

(My limited testing suggests they do not.)

Answer (score 4):

#### Do WebExtensions ever store their prefs within prefs.js?

Not if they are written according to the guidelines.

> Each extension has its own storage area, which can be split into different types of storage.

WebExtensions should be using use the [storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage) to store the settings:

> Enables extensions to store and retrieve data, and listen for changes
>   to stored items.
>
> The storage system is based on the Web Storage API, with a few
>   differences. Among other differences, these include:
>
> - It's asynchronous.
> - Values are scoped to the extension, not to a specific domain (i.e. the same set of key/value pairs are available to all scripts in
>     the background context and content scripts).
> - The values stored can be any JSON-ifiable value, not just String. Among other things, this includes: Array and Object, but only when
>     their contents can can be represented as JSON, which does not include
>     DOM nodes. You don't need to convert your values to JSON Strings prior
>     to storing them, but they are represented as JSON internally, thus the
>     requirement that they be JSON-ifiable.
> - Multiple key/value pairs can be set or retrieved in the same API call.
>
> To use this API you need to include the "storage" permission in your
>   manifest.json file.
>
> **Each extension has its own storage area, which can be split into
>   different types of storage.**
>
> Although this API is similar to Window.localStorage it is recommended
>   that you don't use Window.localStorage in the extension code to store
>   extension-related data. Firefox will clear data stored by extensions
>   using the localStorage API in various scenarios where users clear
>   their browsing history and data for privacy reasons, while data saved
>   using the storage.local API will be correctly persisted in these
>   scenarios.

(emphasis mine).

Source [storage - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Browser Extensions - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions)
- [Implement a settings page - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Implement_a_settings_page)

Comment: Thanks David.  So technically, they *could*, but they should not.  Right?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Looks that way ...

Comment: Considering that WebExtensions have no general access to about:config preferences they have no way to store anything there.